# presents to the best actor trophy

Tags: prepositions, error

Is the boldfaced preposition used correctly in the following? It seems out of place.

> Typically, the previous year's best actor winner presents the current year's best actress award (and the reigning best actress presents **to** the best actor trophy). With Smith's ban, the Oscars will have to break that tradition. [Source](https://lite.cnn.com/en/article/h_5e350e0c409618e38f427f550cf78f37)

Comment: I suspect a typo. _The reigning best actress presents the best actor trophy_ would be the natural way to put it.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you. I thought as much. Btw, does "the reigning best actress"  refer to this year's Best Actress winner or the previous year's Best Actress winner?

Comment: I'm no expert on the Oscars, but it seems clear that it means 'the previous year's winner' as with the male actor, and the writer has expressed it differently to avoid repetition.